# How to create a Function to check the supplied URL against a Whitelist of approved URLs Or Domains before redirecting

Tags: html, vbscript, jasmine, asp-classic

I am new in the Classic ASP, and I want to ask if there's anyone who has experienced and knew of how to create a validation Function in Classic ASP to check the supplied URL against a Whitelist of approved URLs or Domains before redirecting.  Below is the sample codes

```
If not GetNameChk then

  chk = AssignCustAddr(id)

  If UCase(Left(chk,5)) = "ERROR" then
     ReportAnWarning chk, RelConn
  End if
     gostring = "proposer.asp"
Else
     gostring = "CustGet.asp?AddrId=" & encrypt1(trim(request.form("AddrId" & id))) & "&CustId=" & encrypt1(trim(request.form("CustId" & id))) & "&id=" & encrypt1(id) & "&SurName" & id & "="
     gostring = gostring & encrypt1(Replace(trim(request.form("SurName" & id))," ","+"))
     gostring = gostring & "&GivenName" & id & "="
     gostring = gostring & encrypt1(Replace(trim(request.form("GivenName" & id))," ","+"))
     gostring = gostring & "&NRIC" & id & "="
     gostring = gostring & encrypt1(Replace(trim(request.form("nric" & id))," ","+"))
End If                
response.redirect gostring
```

The gostring URL or Domain is need to Validate and Whitelist. Is there anyone knew about this?  Thank you in advance!

I have tried a sort of validation but it's only sanitized(removing the untrusted characters) the value of the URL or Domain please see below

```
Function CRLF(strChar)      
    If strChar ="" Or IsNull(strChar) Then CRLF ="":Exit Function
    Dim strBadChar, arrBadChar, tempChar, I
    strBadChar = "--,+,\,\r,*,%,^,@,!,#,$,(,),[,],{,},;,<,>,~,`,\n," & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(0) & ""
    arrBadChar = Split(strBadChar, ",")
    tempChar = strChar
    For I = 0 To UBound(arrBadChar)
        tempChar = Replace(tempChar, arrBadChar(I), "")
    Next
    tempChar = Replace(tempChar, "@@", "@")      
    CRLF = tempChar     
End Function
```

So, what I am expecting is to check the supplied URL/Domain (gostring) and compare against a whitelist of approved URLs or Domains before redirecting.

Comment: Where is the code that checks against the white list? The SO community will be unable to help you if the problem isn't reasonably well described.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on weather your list of whitelisted URLs is hardcoded or dynamic (read from a DB) i would use either a SELECT CASE statement or a FOR EACH, but it's difficult to give any concrete answer without further information.

Additionaly, I would suggest not naming your function CRLF as it's confusingly close to ASP predefined constant `vbCrLf`.

Lastly, I would have thought that `Exit Function` would get called every time, since the inline if-then only controls the execution of the code up until the `:`. A colon in ASP should be equivalent to a new line in code. Are you sure, your CRLF Function works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The link below provides a means of matching URLs to a whitelist stored in a DB table...

[Find table row match to url input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76637030/ms-sql-server-query-to-find-record-where-column-row-is-part-of-nominated-string)

Using INSTR in a loop it can find a matching record regardless of whether a whole or partial match both ways (from left to right or right to left).