# MS-SQL Server query to find record where column row is part of nominated string using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-express

The query needs to find a record where the value stored in a column row matches the nominated variable. For example the column row value might be `https://example.com/docs/` and the nominated url might be `https://example.com/docs/some.html`.

By using a query like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Documents Where Link LIKE '" & strWebPage & "%' "
```

If

```
Link = "https://example.com/docs/" 
strWebPage = "https://example.com/docs/"
```

then a match is found. Likewise if

```
Link = "https://example.com/docs/some.html" 
strWebpage = "https://example.com/docs/"
```

a match is found as well.

But if

```
Link = "https://example.com/docs/" 
strWebPage = "https://example.com/docs/some.html"
```

then no match is found.

In other words we can find a match if `Link` and `strWebPage` are identical or `strWebPage` is part of `Link`. But we cannot find records where the `Link` value is part of `strWebPage`.

Is there a solution to this problem by using a simple query, meaning without installing full-text search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by performing an INSTR check as a loop within the query.

```
SQL= "SELECT Link FROM Documents "
Set rsSQL = myConnection.Execute(SQL)
if NOT rsSQL.EOF then
    Do While strFound <> "1" and NOT rsSQL.EOF
        strID = rsSQL("ID").value
        strLink = rsSQL("Link").value                               
        if Instr(strWebpage, strLink) <> 0 then
            strFound = "1"
        end if
    rsSQL.MoveNext
    Loop                                
end if
rsSQL.Close
Set rsSQL = Nothing
```

Then when you have the Documents ID you can get its data and move forward...

```
If strFound = "1" then                          
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Documents Where ID = '" & strID & "' "
    Set rsSQL = myConnection.Execute(SQL)   
    if NOT rsSQL.EOF then
        strA = rsSQL("A").value
        strB = rsSQL("B").value     
        strEtc = rsSQL("Etc").value                         
    end if
    rsSQL.Close
    Set rsSQL = Nothing
else
    do other stuff
end if
```

Comment: I don't recall if INSTR, which was available for Access DB queries but not for SQL queries, ever worked both ways, but using it like this example has solved my problem, thanks.